# Usuário que não dá atenção às suas perguntas

Tags: debate

Me deparei com um [usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30051/carlos-rocha?tab=topactivity) que faz muitas perguntas e que deixa a maioria em aberto. Não responde aos comentários (até responde mas em certo ponto não responde mais) e parece que simplesmente abandona as perguntas.

Fiz a conta:

```
182 perguntas
112 estão abertas
isso significa 61,5% de perguntas abertas
```

Eu acho isso péssimo porque fica parecendo que o usuário não tem muito interesse na comunidade, mas apenas em resolver a sua situação de forma pragmática.

Na sua [última pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/296586/8063) eu deixei um recado para que ele reveja a sua participação no site.

É válido intimar o usuário a resolver as suas perguntas sem solução ou deixar ele à vontade?

Comment: Infelizmente já passei por a mesma situação com esse mesmo usuário. Não querendo instigar nada, fico com a sensação que ele não quer aprender mas sim apenas fazer com que a coisa funcione de qualquer forma possível (mesmo que não seja boa). Por isso neste momento quando reparo que a pergunta é dele, rapidamente a fecho.

Comment: Outro exemplo é [este usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/69048/wagner-martins-bodyboard?tab=topactivity). Ele faz uma pergunta atrás da outra e vai abandonando as que ele parece não ter mais interesse, e as perguntas são quase todas sobre o mesmo assunto.

Comment: [Mais um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300928/8063) que abandona as perguntas e faz outra seguida com o mesmo propósito.

Comment: Acaba por ser as vezes um mal comum. Muitos assumem que isto é tipo um forum, e mal obtêm algo que permite minimamente resolver o problema, rapidamente abandonam. Desde que se consiga incutir algum sentido de responsabilidade aos usuários já acho que é uma vitória. Mas não me parece que vá ser muito facil

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No passado até mostrava quem aceita as respostas ou não. De uns tempos pra cá a SE tem mostrado que prefere dar atenção a quem pergunta e não a quem responde, talvez por isso a qualidade geral tenha caído aqui e no SOen. Quem responde deveria ser mais valorizado.

Se todas ações da SE vão por este caminho não vejo muito o que fazer.

Acho isso prejudicial porque estraga a ideia de comunidade e de aprendizado. Vira uma robotização das ações.

Acredito que fez o certo, mas não posso falar pela SE, outros moderadores ou a comunidade como um todo. Sempre tome cuidado para não ofender e não tentar tirar proveito próprio naquilo. Veja o contexto, entenda se é a hora de fazer aquilo.

Acho a ação do Isac boa também, desde que não se transforme em perseguição (pelo que conheço dele, não deve ocorrer). Sei que há quem discorde (da ação, não da boa intenção do Isac :) ).

Aproveito para dizer que a reputação obtida com perguntas é desproporcionalmente grande (já foi igual) e deveria ser revisto. Há muitos usuário que basicamente só sugam e tem altas reputações.

Comment: Não quero que interpretem erradamente as minhas ações, tanto que nem sequer voto nas questões dele. Não faço qualquer tipo de perseguição, simplesmente não vou tentar ajudar uma pessoa que parece não estar interessada em aprender a fazer correto. Pelo menos para mim acaba por um pouco desmotivador, quando vejo que a pessoa parece não estar nem ai, e acaba fazendo do jeito que inicialmente estava a fazer desde que funcione.

Comment: Está certo. Ninguém em sã consciência poderia te recriminar (embora hoje dia os loucos estejam tomando conta do manicômio :) )